# How can I add an integer to an existing record?

Tags: c#

Please be kind enough to tell me how I can add an integer to an existing record which starts with a string sequence like the following;

S0000 - S00027

Kind Regards,
Indunil Sanjeewa

Comment: is that last existing record a string?

Comment: yes. example : S00009

Answer (score 0):

The logic is:

1. separate the "S00009" into "S" and "00009". Use string method `Substring()`
2. Parse "00009" into integer. Use `Int.Parse` or `Int.TryParse`
3. Add 1 into the integer
4. Print back the "S" and the integer. Use `string.Concat` or simply  `string + integer`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
string record = "S00009";
string recordPrefix = "S";
char paddingCharacter = '0';
string recordNoPart = record.Substring(recordPrefix.Length);
int nextRecordNo = int.Parse(recordNoPart) + 1;
string nextRecord = string.Format("{0}{1}", recordPrefix, nextRecordNo.ToString().PadLeft(record.Length - recordPrefix.Length, paddingCharacter));
```

@kurakura88 has already given the logic. I have just provided the hardcore c# code.

Comment: I would say my solution is correct but simultaneously I would also agree that a better implementation can be there and you have already provided that but you too have missed something :).

Comment: Nevermind what I said. Thanks for providing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following approach

```
string input = @"S0000";
string pattern = @"\d+";
string format = @"0000";
int addend = 1;

string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern,
    m => (int.Parse(m.Value) + addend).ToString(format));

// result = S0001
```

Regular expression `\d+` matches all digits.

`MatchEvaluator` converts matched value to integer. Then adds the addend. Then converts the value to a string using the specified format.

In the end using the `Replace` method replaces the previous value with the new value.